# Will inserted records during a test be deleted?

Tags: apex

I wrote a test that inserts several records into salesforce like so (psudocode):

```
@isTest
static testmethod testAccount() {

Account__c acct = new Account__c(
  Name = 'TESTPROJ',
  Title = 'TESTTEST'
);

insert acct;

// ... and so on
}
```

If i insert records during an test apex test will they be deleted? So far in all my tests i usually run a query and delete them in my test. After a coworker reviewed my code she indicated that it's not necessary. Is this true?

I did a a couple google searches and had no luck and wasn't successful finding anything in the [Apex reference guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, all records you insert in test methods will never get committed to the database. You don't have to worry about cleaning up after yourself with Apex tests.

Here's a little bit more [information](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_run_tests.htm&language=en_US):

> Unit test methods take no arguments, commit no data to the database,
>   send no emails, and are flagged with the testMethod keyword in the
>   method definition.